# How to batch update data in mysql using their ordered sequence info?

Tags: mysql, sql

say, i have a table t with only 2 fields, like below

```
ID    VALUE
---------------------
0      100   
0      103   
0      101   
0      102  
...
...
...
0      110,000,000
```

i need to update the id fields using their ordered sequence and change the table , like below:

```
ID    VALUE
---------------------
1      100   
2      101   
3      102   
4      103   
...
...
...
109999901       110,000,000
```

How do i write the sql script in mysql to make this happen? Seems like in Oracle it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, row_number() over (order by value) as seqnum
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.value = tt.value
    set t.id = tt.seqnum;
```

However, a better method might use variables:

```
set @rn := 0;

update t
    set id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by value;
```

For these, you would want an index on `(value)`.  You would have better performance by just creating a new table, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then I suggest actually *not* doing this update, but instead just use a select along with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), VALUE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID;
```

You could also put the above select into a view and use that if you have a frequent need to view your data in this way.  The reason for not wanting to do an update is that should you insert new `ID` values which occur in the middle of your current sequence, you might be forced to run the update again.  This could get to be a burden after a while.